# Can I access the originating $USER variable from within a script run with `sudo`?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, environment-variables

A weird question, I know. Here's the script:

```
echo $USER
```

Here's the command I use to run it:

```
sudo ./myscript.sh
```

Right now it prints "root" but I want it to print `jon`, my username. Is there a way to do that by changing the script, and not the command?

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do it. But maybe the easiest way is a work-around. Call that script from another script, where you 'save' your user id so that the 'sudo script' can access it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Use the `SUDO_USER` environment variable instead of `USER`.

`sudo` places the name of the user who ran it in the `SUDO_USER` environment variable:

```
ek@Io:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo $USER'
[sudo] password for ek:
root
ek@Io:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo $SUDO_USER'
ek
```

So you can simply replace `$USER` with `$SUDO_USER` in your script:

```bsh
echo $SUDO_USER
```

#### Further Reading

- [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sudo.8.html), in the section on "ENVIRONMENT":

  ```
  SUDO_USER        Set to the login name of the user who invoked sudo.
  ```

  The manpage also describes some other related environment variables defined by `sudo` that may come in handy, such as `SUDO_UID` and `SUDO_GID`
- [Getting $USER inside shell script when running with sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629605/getting-user-inside-shell-script-when-running-with-sudo)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@Eliah Kagan's answer above](https://askubuntu.com/a/866573/367990), I would like to point out that you can also easily have an expansion which works both if it runs in a `sudo` context or not:

```bsh
echo "${SUDO_USER:-$USER}"
```

This expands to the value of `$SUDO_USER` by default, but if if that variable is unset or empty, it falls back to the value of `$USER`.

```bsh
$ bash -c 'echo "${SUDO_USER:-$USER}"'
bytecommander

$ sudo bash -c 'echo "${SUDO_USER:-$USER}"'
bytecommander
```

More information about default parameter expansion in Bash can be found e.g. on https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value.