# how to capture a string (text) written in the terminal and put it in a variable

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, scripts

how to capture a string (text) written in the terminal and put it in a variable into same script (run with sudo). Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -p "Put your username: " UNAME
myusername="Value of UNAME"
```

Or how to get the name of the non-root user (echo $USER) from a bash script **with sudo** and put it in a variable

Comment: If I understand your second question correctly, you can use `$SUDO_USER`. See [Can I access the originating $USER variable from within a script run with `sudo`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866567/can-i-access-the-originating-user-variable-from-within-a-script-run-with-sudo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `read -p <prompt string> <variable>`, the string that the user inputs is stored in . In your example, the user input would be stored in `UNAME`. If you need this input somewhere else, you can just use `$UNAME`. There is no reason to transfer the value over to `myusername`, you can `read` into `myusername` directly, or use `UNAME` later in the script.

As for the second question, there is no one consistent way to get the non-root user. There are a few ways that work on various distros, see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629605/getting-user-inside-shell-script-when-running-with-sudo), but it depends what distro and version you're running and how you have things configured. If you can call `sudo` *inside* the script and get $USER beforehand, that would work as well, but the user would be prompted for their password during script execution, and that may not be desirable.